# Determine if an event was consumed in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to do some off-piste stuff with event handling in JavaFX. I need to be able to determine if an event was consumed after I manually fire it.

In the following example a synthetic mouse event is correctly received, however calling consume() does not update the event.

I've debugged this and found JavaFX actually creates a new event instance so the original is unchanged

```
public class EventManipulation extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            System.out.println("dragged");
            event.consume();
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new HBox(button), 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();

        MouseEvent event = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, 0, 0, 0, 0, MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1, false, false,
                false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, null);
        Event.fireEvent(button, event);
        System.out.println(event.isConsumed());  // <== prints false
    }
}
```

I've discovered EventDispatchChain, however I cannot figure out how to get this to work. The button can generate a event dispatch chain but requires one to start off with... The following fails because I don't know how to create an initial tail.

```
Event result = button.buildEventDispatchChain(null).dispatchEvent(event);
System.out.println(result.isConsumed());
```

Comment: On what thread do you fire and on what thread does the event get dispatched? Maybe add Thread.Sleep()?

Comment: @alex440 On JavaFX thread... Application.start() is always run on the JavaFX thread.

Comment: @alex440 - wouldn't help if fx internals copy the event, or?

Comment: I think the function terminates before the event had a chance to be handled.

Comment: @alex440 no, `fireEvent` is not asynchronous, when it returns the event has been fully processed.  The problem is that the original event is not consumed, as events are copied while being dispatched.  The only way to see if it was consumed is to build your own event chain, and use that to fire the event and then check if the resulting event `== null` (consumed) or `!= null` (not consumed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I have for this is to implement the [EventDispatchChain](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/event/EventDispatchChain.html) interface. A fairly minimal interface is as follows. Unfortunately the built in version used by javafx is in a non-accessible package - `com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl`

```
private class SimpleChain implements EventDispatchChain {

    private Deque<EventDispatcher> dispatchers = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public EventDispatchChain append(EventDispatcher eventDispatcher) {
        dispatchers.addLast(eventDispatcher);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public EventDispatchChain prepend(EventDispatcher eventDispatcher) {
        dispatchers.addFirst(eventDispatcher);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Event dispatchEvent(Event event) {
        if (dispatchers.peekFirst() != null) {
            Event result = dispatchers.removeFirst().dispatchEvent(event, this);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            } else {
                event.consume();
                return event;
            }
        } else {
            return event;
        }
    }
}
```

This then produces expected result when used like this

```
Event result = button.buildEventDispatchChain(new SimpleChain()).dispatchEvent(event);
System.out.println(result.isConsumed());
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with the `SimpleChain` implementation, but using a copy of `EventDispatcherImpl` it did work.  I think modifying the chain (instead of providing a copy) when calling `dispatchEvent(Event, EventDispatcher)` is the cause.  `EventDispatcherImpl` is taking great care to restore the original chain after that call.