# JavaFX - auto hide window on mouse over

Tags: java, javafx, desktop-application

### Goal

I need to create a javafx stage which hides when mouse move over it, but show when mouse is not over my stage. *My stage* should,

- Hide when I bring mouse pointer on to it
- Show when mouse pointer is on any place of screen other than on *my stage*
- Allow to click/focus through it, when it is hidden

### Problem

Although it seems like a very easy task, I cannot figure out how to do it correctly. Yes, we can easily implement the logic to hide the stage (using mouse event listeners). But, when showing the hidden stage, it seems so difficult as the hidden stage cannot listen to any mouse event.

- Can we implement this without low-level system-wide logic?
- If so, how can we implement it? Can anyone suggest a good approach?
- If we need to use low-level system-wide logic how can we do it while keeping platform independent support?

Comment: try creating a full-screen always-on-top transparent stage that records mouse events but doesn't consume them.

Comment: @SergeyGrinev Thanks, but when it doesn't consume mouse events how can we listen to mouse events?

Comment: Tharindu, you can still use event, just let it go further, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538364/determine-if-an-event-was-consumed-in-javafx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaFX you can use the `javafx.scene.robot.Robot` to get the mouse pointer locations. Then the job will be very easy for you.

As an example you could do something like this,

```
Bounds interfaceBounds = ...;
Robot robot = new Robot();
```

An assume you have two functions for hide/show the interface.

```
void hide() { ... }
void show() { ... }
```

Then you the following code in another thread (timer).

```
Point2D urMouse = robot.getMousePosition();
if( !interfaceBounds.contains( urMouse ) )
{
    hide();
}else{
    show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works only with `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT`. Only option I can see to it make work with any `StageStyle` is to create two stages. One should be only hoverProperty listener.

```java
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
    
    public class App extends Application {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 400, 400);
            scene.setFill(null);
            
            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            
            ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue) {
                    stackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.01);");
                } else {
                    stackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                }
            };
            stackPane.hoverProperty().addListener(listener);
            listener.changed(stackPane.hoverProperty(), null, stackPane.isHover());
        }
    }
```